# Is switching from Hyper-v over to VMware using the same hardware possible?

Tags: hyper-v, hardware

I am a newbie into the world of virtualization. Presently, I have a server with the H/W details given below:

**Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Quad CPU Q8400  @2.66GHz(4 CPUs), ~2.7GHz
Memory: 6144 MB RAM (3*2GB, DDR2) 
HDD: Seagate 500GB, 7200.12
USB HDD External: Seagate 250GB**

I have been using Windows 2008 since the last six months using the H/W mentioned above. Now if I want to load Hypervisor ESXi 5.5 from VMware directly on the same H/W, will it be possible?

Another question pops up in my mind: Is Internet connectivity mandatory  if down the line I decide to go ahead with vCenter?

Looking forward to your responses!

Answer (score 2):

If your hardware is on the [VMWare HCL](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php), switching will be possible. Otherwise, it might still work but is unsupported by VMWare (and would likely be [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here).